# Mac vs Windows: Command Key for Mac; CTRL key for windows

Tags: javascript, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm having trouble determining if this is possible. I want to add a shortcut to the app so that users can select all of the images on the page by typing the following:

On OSX: `Command+A`
On Windows: `CTRL+A`

The issue is the `Command+A` combo in jQuery is done by checking the `metaKey` value. How do I bind the `CTRL+A` combo for windows, but ensure it doesn't get bound on Mac's?

Comment: Maybe try to detect the OS first, and go from there?

Comment: I'd agree; simply make use of the META key inside of a conditional that checks the OS.

Comment: I thought about that option, but was hoping their was a detection method that would be in line with how Modernizr works to detect a Command key.

Answer (score 0):

I did find a good way to fix it. we have to determine the platform.

```js
/mac/i.test(navigator.platform)
```